# Codeigniter - Getting "thumbnail_url" from youtube video JSON response

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to save a thumbnail img URL from a youtube video through its JSON response.

The user submits a youtube link through a form first.

Controller:

```
$data['video_thumb'] = $this->gallery_model->get_youtube('link');


        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('media/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Model:

```
function get_youtube($url){

        $youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $url ."&format=json";

        $curl = curl_init($youtube);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $return = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $result = json_decode($return, true);

        $video_thumb = $result->thumbnail_url;
        $video_thumb = str_replace('"\"','',$video_thumb);

        return $video_thumb;
    }
```

View:

```
<?php echo $video_thumb; ?>
```

I am new to codeigniter and coding in general, I realize my structure might not be the most appropiate.

so far, when I render the view, This appears:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: video_thumb
```

Why is this happening? can you suggest me a better way to do this? Thanks!
So far, I'm just printing out the thumbnail_url to see if the get_youtube function is working, but apparently not.

thanks again! :)

Comment: How are you calling your view?

Comment: updated the controller, the 'link' comes from the a form field

Comment: Still returns as undefined variable

Answer (score 2):

You are generating an array from the json response with this line:

```
$result = json_decode($return, true);
```

([see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) you should see a "PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object" error too somewhere.

So the `$result->thumbnail_url` should be `$result['thumbnail_url']` instead, or you can drop the second `true` from the `json_decode()`'s parameters that would work too.